# What does '@'%' mean in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I saw following mysql permission grant syntax

`mysql> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'encrypted_user'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;`

I couldn't understand the meaning of `'@'%'`. what does that mean ?

If someone has opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: It's to define where the user is allowed to access the database from. Think of it this way, `THE USER` `@` `THE HOST THEY CAN ACCESS FROM`. `%` Indicates they can access it from anywhere (i.e. any computer, any ip, etc.) whereas if you were to use `localhost` as an example - would mean you can only access the database from the same server (aka, localhost), or receive an access denied type error. (*in simple terms, of course*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@` divides the username and host.

`%` stands for "any".

So your example grants permissions to user `encrypted_user` accessing the DB from any host.

Example when you'd separate the permissions: You want a user to have read-write permissions accessing the DB from localhost, but read-only from remote host.

Comment: "accessing the DB on any host." --- **from** any host.

Comment: +1. In case it's not obvious from this answer: there's no `'@'%'`. Rather, it's `'encrypted_user'`, plus `@`, plus `'%'`.